# Ammunition code in game driving me bonkers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to program a system in an FPS unity game where every time you deplete 12 bullets the program takes another 12 from a stock pile. The issue is, if the stock pile is greater than 12, and you deplete the 12 bullets already loaded into your gun, the entire stockpile disappears. Ive scanned my code and am completely perplexed as to how to fix this error. The main code for this operation is below.

```
if (bulletsLeft <= 1) 
{
    if (extraBullets > 0)
    {
        if (extraBullets <= 12)
            bulletsLeft += extraBullets;

        extraBullets -= extraBullets;
    }

    if (extraBullets >= 12)
    {
        bulletsLeft += 12;
        extraBullets -= 12;
    }
}
```

Comment: `extraBullets -= extraBullets;` is the same as `extraBullets = 0;`

Comment: the part you shared looks sort of all right, have you tried adding lots of Debug.Log calls all over the place to help you find what's wrong?

Comment: You forgot to put braces after `if (extraBullets <= 12)` so `extraBullets -= extraBullets;` is always executed (if `extraBullets > 0` is true)

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code, rather than scanning it? stepping thru your running code should always be your first step.

Comment: There, I have fixed indenting for you. See anything weird? (Hint: read @UnholySheep's comment)

Answer (score 2):

Since you forgot the braces, your code ...

```
if (extraBullets <= 12)
    bulletsLeft += extraBullets;
    extraBullets -= extraBullets;
```

... is equivalent to

```
if (extraBullets <= 12) {
    bulletsLeft += extraBullets;
}
extraBullets -= extraBullets; // No more bullets after this!
```

The next statement ...

```
if (extraBullets >= 12)
```

... will never be performed.

---

I suggest to simplify the logic and to first determine how many bullets to transfer from the stock pile. Then perform the transfer.

```
if (bulletsLeft <= 1) {
    int transferBullets = extraBullets < 12 ? extraBullets : 12;
    bulletsLeft += transferBullets;
    extraBullets -= transferBullets;
}
```

The assignment with the ternary expression...

```
int transferBullets = extraBullets < 12 ? extraBullets : 12;
```

... is equivalent to

```
int transferBullets;
if (extraBullets < 12) {
    transferBullets = extraBullets;
} else {
    transferBullets = 12;
}
```

According to @Kyle and @UnholySheep, you can also write this instead:

```
int transferBullets = Math.Min(12, extraBullets);
```

Comment: `int transferBullets = Math.Min(12, extraBullets);` might be slightly clearer than using the ternary operator. At least to me it more clearly communicates the intent.

Comment: Yes. Is there `Math.Min` in Unity?  (I'm not Unity programmer)

Comment: Unity has access to the entire .NET standard library